# print out variable in procmail

Tags: linux, sed, awk, procmail

I have a Procmail recipe to filter incoming mail such as below:

```
:0
*^Subject:.*(test)
* ? egrep -is -f /root/Procmail/whitelist.txt
{            
    :0 fwb
    | formail -I ""
    
    :0
    myfolder/
}
```

The above recipe function is to filter out the body content of the email and forward that mail to `myfolder`.
The problem is I have a variable that I want to put inside the body.

```
FROM_=`formail -c -x"From " \
     | expand | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//g' -e 's/[ ]*$//g' \
     | awk '{ print $1 }'`

    SUBJ_=`formail -c -x"Subject:" \
     | expand \
     | sed -e 's/  */ /g' \
     | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//g' -e 's/[ ]*$//g'`
```

This email body (together with the variable) should be forwarded to `myfolder`.

I've tried to `echo` the variable like this but still no use.

```
:0 fwb
echo "${SUBJ_}"
echo "{FROM_}"
```

Is the something wrong with my recipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pipe into the shell script.  An action without a prefix saves to a folder named "echo", in your case.

You were also lacking a dollar sign on the `${FROM_}` variable.

```
:0 fwb
| ( echo "${SUBJ_}";  echo "${FROM_}" )
```

Your assignments could probably be optimized quite a bit.  Piping `sed` to `sed` or `awk` is rarely necessary; if `sed` cannot handle what you want, then let `awk` do it all.

```
FROM_=`formail -c -x"From " \
 | expand \
 | awk '{ gsub (/^[ ]*|[ ]*$/,""); print $1 }'`

SUBJ_=`formail -c -x"Subject:" \
 | expand \
 | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/^[ ]*//g' -e 's/[ ]*$//g'`
```

(Not sure why you would need `expand` in there either, but I left it in just in case.)